# Expand/hide collapsible using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to implement expandable menu. Only one heading should be expanded. When user clicks on another one, content of the previously
expanded heading should hide. I have used code from w3schools, but I don't know how to automatically hide previous heading.

```js
      var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
      var i;

      for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var content = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
          }
        });
      }
```

```html
<h2>Collapsibles</h2>

          <p>A Collapsible:</p>
          <button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
          <div class="content">
            <p>text</p>
           </div>

      <p>Collapsible Set:</p>
      <button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
      <button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>text.</p>
      </div>
      <button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply collapse opened collapsible `on click` by JS:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
      var i;

      for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          var content = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
            content.style.opacity = 0;
          } else {
            if(node=document.querySelector(".collapsible.active")){
              node.classList.toggle("active",false);
              node.nextElementSibling.style.opacity = 0;
            }
            content.style.opacity = 1;
          }
          this.classList.toggle("active");
        });
      }
```

```css
.content{
opacity:0;
transition:opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<h2>Collapsibles</h2>

          <p>A Collapsible:</p>
          <button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
          <div class="content">
            <p>text</p>
           </div>

      <p>Collapsible Set:</p>
      <button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>text1</p>
      </div>
      <button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>text2</p>
      </div>
      <button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>text3</p>
      </div>
```

Or, to use with `height`, you'll need to add `overflow-y:hidden` to hide it completely:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
      for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.trace()
        debugger
          var content = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
            content.style.height = 0;
          } else {
            if(node=document.querySelector(".collapsible.active")){
              node.classList.toggle("active",false);
              node.nextElementSibling.style.height = 0;
            }
            content.style.height = content.scrollHeight+"px";
          }
          this.classList.toggle("active");
        });
      }
```

```css
.content{
height:0;
transition:height 0.5s;
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2>Collapsibles</h2>

          <p>A Collapsible:</p>
          <button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>text1</p>
      </div>
      <p>Collapsible Set:</p>
      <button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>text1</p>
      </div>
      <button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>text2</p>
      </div>
      <button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>text3</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one more question - I want text to be animated, not just to pop-out. I tried adding this to my CSS:
'.content {
transition-timing-function: ease-in;
transition: 0.2s; } '
But it doesn't work, do you have idea what can I do?
Thanks

Comment: @Linaelena The problem with the animation is that CSS `display` property *[isn't animatable](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp)*. So I edited my answer to use another property (in this case `opacity`), and added translation to it. So I hope that this will help you!

Comment: It is useful, but it leaves blank space between buttons. I saw an example using content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px"; and content.style.maxHeight = null; in js and in css: ' .content {max-height: 0;  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out; } ' Can I use something like this instead of opacity? I'm total beginner, still not so familiar with syntax.

Comment: @Linaelena Yes, you can, but add `overflow-y: hidden`, to make collapsibles collapse completely. See my answer!

Answer (score 1):

A more readable way to do this is to divide your code in functions, like this:

```
<script>
    function hideOthers(actual) {
      var contentDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
      contentDivs.forEach(others => {
        if (others !== actual) {
          others.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
    }

    function toggleDisplay(div) {
      if (div.style.display === "block") {
        div.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        div.style.display = "block";
      }
    }

    function onContentLoaded() {
      var collapsibleDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible");

      collapsibleDivs.forEach(div => {
        div.addEventListener('click', e => {
          var clicked = e.srcElement;
          var sibling = clicked.nextElementSibling;

          toggleDisplay(sibling);
          hideOthers(sibling);
        })
      })
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onContentLoaded);
  </script>
```

Notice I've just changed your JS script and I've used `document.querySelectorAll` to get all elements with a given class, `forEach` function to iterate over elements, *arrow functions* to provide callbacks and `e.srcElement` to get the clicked element on the click handler. Hope it help you. Welcome to SO!